# vb.net applications to reload the INI file

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke, ini, user32

i write this code to change default printer in windows and work fine but in reload the INI file have a error
this is a code :

```
 Private Sub SetDefaultPrinter(ByVal PrinterName As String, ByVal DriverName As String, ByVal PrinterPort As String)
    Dim DeviceLine As String

    'rebuild a valid device line string
    DeviceLine = PrinterName & "," & DriverName & "," & PrinterPort

    'Store the new printer information in the
    '[WINDOWS] section of the WIN.INI file for
    'the DEVICE= item
    Call WriteProfileString("windows", "Device", DeviceLine)

    'Cause all applications to reload the INI file
    Call SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, 0, "windows")

End Sub

Private Declare Function WriteProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "WriteProfileStringA" (ByVal lpszSection As String, ByVal lpszKeyName As String, ByVal lpszString As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lparam As String) As Long
Private Const HWND_BROADCAST As Long = &HFFFF&
Private Const WM_WININICHANGE As Long = &H1A
```

and this is a error :

> A call to PInvoke function 'Test!Test.Form2::SendMessage' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?
Thankful

Comment: www.pinvoke.net

Comment: @Plutonix Not much point recommending a site like that, so full of errors as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByVal lparam As String) As Long
```

Your data types are wrong. The `hwnd` parameter is pointer sized, `wMsg` is a 32 bit value, and `wParam`, `lParam` and the return value are pointer sized. Note that `Long` is a 64 bit type.

Instead it should be

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, _
    ByVal lparam As String) As IntPtr
```

Note that I recommend that, in the modern day, you use pinvoke declarations rather than `Declare`. This offer much more flexibility.